# Debugging Multiple Projects which are in different solutions in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I have four different solutions: two C/C++ libraries, a C++/CLI wrapper which uses those libraries and a WPF project.

How can I debug my libraries when they are called by my WPF Project?

Comment: Just to be sure I'm understanding this correctly you mean you are calling your libraries in your WPF project and you would like the debugging to work when you call it?

Comment: I'm Calling a function in C++/CLI library which in turn calls a function in one of those libraries. I'm able to debug till the C++/CLI wrapper , but I'm not able to debug the function which the wrapper calls.

Comment: Well it looks like I understood more or less the problem then. Make sure your libraries are compiled in debug mode and that you're putting the .pdb files somewhere Visual Studio can find them.

Comment: My question is to which project do i need to add the location of the .pdb files? should i add it to  the WPF application or to the C++/CLI wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to debug anything you call that is outside your solution, you need to help Visual Studio find the debugger information. If you just link to a library it can run code but you can't do step by step debugging becuse you're only linking binaries and not source code.

For debugging external libraries, you need **two things**:

- link the library files compiled in debug mode
- tell Visual Studio   where to find the .pdb files (which contain useful information for debugging).

To make sure the .pdb files are loaded correctly, you can go in your project options then Debugging->Symbols and then select the directory where the .pdb files from your library are. Visual Studio will put the .pdb files in the release directory usually (default settings).

**Important note:** that since you are using a wrapper over the libraries, you need to make sure that the wrapper itself is also doing this (or you will only be able to debug the wrapper).

Comment: I'm Calling a function in C++/CLI library which in turn calls a function in one of those libraries. I'm able to debug till the C++/CLI wrapper , but I'm not able to debug the function which the wrapper calls

Comment: My question is to which project do i need to add the location of the .pdb files? should i add it to the WPF application or to the C++/CLI wrapper?

Comment: You add id to the project your debugging from so the WPF application

Comment: What happens when you try to step in library functions?

Comment: I cannot debug the library functions.. In the C++/CLI wrapper , when i keep a break point to the library function , the debugger will not step in to the library function.. It just debugs the next statement after the library function call from the wrapper.

Comment: I see. So what if you put some `for(;;)` in the library function you're calling and pause the execution? What do you get on the callstack? Do you get some "need debugging symbols" or something like that?